# how to create different zoom levels for a world map

Tags: linux, web-applications

we are developing an application similar to google maps. We are able to sucessfully transfer images from server to clent. we want to provide zooming capability to the images transferred to the clients. we are using Ubuntu for our application.

Thanks

-Roy

Comment: @roy- if you people are being able to develop a service as good as google maps, then you people should also be able to solve this problem yourself. you people seem to be like masterminds. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at OpenStreetMap's [Slippery Map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map) where they did basically what you want for the OSM project.